# PHPExcel and Office 2016

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm currently using PHPExcel (v1.8.0) to generate an xlxs file with datas and graph. But when I open my generated document in office I get an error. I've tried to precise the orientation with the "setPlotDirection" method, and delete the y axis label.

This is the code :

```
$categories = array(
            new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', "'".$this->oSheet->getTitle()."'!\$A$5:\$A$31", null, 1)
        );
        $values = array(
            new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', "'".$this->oSheet->getTitle()."'!\$BA$5:\$BA$31", null, 1),
        );
        $this->createChart($categories, $values, 'Title', 'Xlegend', 'YLegend', 'A34', 'K50');

function createChart($categories, $values, $title, $xLegnd, $yLegend, $topLeft, $bottomRight)
    {
        $series = new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
            \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,
            \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,
            range(0, count($values) - 1),
            null,
            $categories,
            $values
        );

        $series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_VERTICAL);

        $layout = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
        $layout->setShowVal(true);

        $plotArea = new \PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(null, array($series));
        $title = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title($title);
        $yAxisLabel = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title($yLegend);
        $xAxisLabel = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title($xLegnd);
        $chart = new \PHPExcel_Chart(
            $title,
            $title,
            null,
            $plotArea,
            true,
            0,
            null,
            $yAxisLabel
        );

        $chart->setTopLeftPosition($topLeft);
        $chart->setBottomRightPosition($bottomRight);
        $this->oSheet->addChart($chart);
    }
```

All works fine with Excel 2010/2011 and Libre Office. But I get this error with Excel 2016 :

```
<recoveryLog>
    <logFileName>error066200_01.xml</logFileName>
    <summary>Des erreurs ont été détectées dans le fichier xxx</summary>
    <removedParts>
        <removedPart>Partie supprimée: /xl/drawings/drawing3.xml partie.  (Forme de dessin)</removedPart>
    </removedParts>
</recoveryLog>
```

Any idea ?
Thanks